# Setting a filter search on 3 characters entry on android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

I want to put a filter search while typing in AutoCompleteTextView in Android.
Means, it should search only after user types at least 3 characters in AutoCompleteTextView.

```
final AutoCompleteTextView countryTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

Now, I want that, if user types 3 characters , only then filtering starts.

Any help..

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line of code:

```
final AutoCompleteTextView countryTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

countryTextView.setThreshold(num);
```

// num is number of characters.